Nikon D40 only wakes up after pressing reset button - why?
My trusty Nikon D40 suddenly wouldn't power up.
So I tried 2 freshly charged batteries and still nothing.
The only way it will power up is if I press the reset button hidden next to the USB port - then it wakes up and will function fine (including taking pictures) until it goes into sleep mode and does not wake up again (until I repeat the reset button!).
I have trawled the internet and haven't found anything that helps. I don't like writing off the camera as it still took great photos and I have AF-S lenses that fit it.
Has anyone come across this problem before or have an explanation as to why it won't start up unless it has a physical "reset"?

Vaguely sounds similar to how a camera might not respond to power on if the internal (clock) battery charge is too low, regardless of the main battery being fully charged. Some cameras allow access to change this little clock battery, the D40 does not. Physical reset button might be doing something sufficiently different to the main power button that theres enough charge left to fire it up. On the D40 this is called the backup battery and is mounted on the battery box internally. Alternatively there might be problem with the power switch, corrosion, etc

You are likely to be right about it being an internal clock battery. The symptoms are consistent with that. I looked for a replaceable backup battery but couldn't find any means of access to one. Is the internal battery accessible if I opened up the case (not that I know how to do that as yet!).

Its a bit elaborate  - https://i.sstatic.net/Z4ckgSBm.png / the maintenance/repair manual is here: http://ss-it.de/data/servicemanuals/D40.pdf HTH

Thanks - It looks like a challenge to strip it down and get access to the backup battery, but I may as well try it. I have found a youtube video that may help me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYu-mzDM5B8
